# Tailwind background, width, and height not working

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I wonder why my div didn't show any background

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="h-100 w-100 bg-black"/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: There is no `h-100`. Try `h-96`.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? (preferably with more information on how you're importing and building Tailwind)

Answer (score 0):

it is working fine, the class you have used does not exist. It is only till `h-96` and `w-96` https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/height